# OnSelect show current date on jquery datepicker calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using a Jquery datepicker. I just want to show the current day on the calendar when it pops up, but i do not want it to be selected (like when using setDate function).

My datepicker:

```js
    $('#<%=effdatepicker.ClientID%>').datepicker({
                      changeMonth: false,
                      changeYear: false,
                      minDate: cutoff,
                      showOn: "both",
                      buttonImageOnly: true,
                      buttonText: "Select date",

                  }).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
              });
```

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="effdatepicker" Width="100px" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you only want show today date in the calendar but not allow to be change? If yes:

```
$('#<%=effdatepicker.ClientID%>').datepicker({
  changeMonth: false,
  changeYear: false,
  minDate: 0,
  maxDate: 0,
  showOn: "both",
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  buttonText: "Select date",
}).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```

Comment: Nope. The datepicker is going to have a value when the program is run. Say, for example the datepicker textbox has the date 4/4/16, and when i click on it , the calendar pop up should take me to current date instead of 4/4/16. Hope I made myself clear :)

Comment: Maybe you can play around with beforeShow.

Answer (score 0):

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pewLusad/)

```
 onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
       var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
       var dayOfWeek = weekday[date.getUTCDay() + 1];
       var selectedMonthName = months[$("#CheckInDate").datepicker('getDate').getMonth()];
       $('#checkInDateDiv').html(dateText.split('/')[1]);
       var dayandady = dayOfWeek + '<br>' + selectedMonthName;
       $("#checkInDateSpan").html(dayandady);
       var t = $("#CheckInDate").datepicker("getDate");
       t.setDate(t.getDate() + 1);
       $("#CheckOutDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", t)

     },
```